# Multi-line graphs in R using ggplot2- Percents not displaying unless we create a seperate dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, linegraph

I am trying to create a multiple line graph in R using ggplot 2.  We are looking to track the percentage of individuals at two different locations over time (6 time points total).  We want to use a line graph.

Here is an example of what my data looks like.

```
    time <- c("t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
          "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
          "t3", "t3", "t3", "t3", "t3", "t3", 
          "t4", "t4", "t4", "t4", "t4", "t4", 
          "t5", "t5", "t5", "t5", "t5", "t5", 
          "t6", "t6", "t6", "t6", "t6", "t6")
location <- c ("L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", 
               "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", 
               "L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", 
               "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", 
               "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", 
               "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L1", "L2")
data <- data.frame (time, location)
data
table (data$time, exclude = FALSE)
table (data$location, exclude = FALSE)
table (data$location, data$time, exclude = FALSE)
```

I have looked at several posts on this topic and I have been able to generate a graph that has two different lines but the y axis is not showing the percentage.  Here is the current code.

```
ggplot (data = data, 
        mapping = aes (
          x = time, 
          y = location,
          group = location, 
          color = location
        )) + 
  geom_point (stat = "identity", size = 3) + 
  geom_line (stat = "identity") + 
  ggtitle("Percentage of individuals at a given location over time") + 
  xlab("Time") + 
  ylab ("Percent") +
  coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0, 100))
```

I have seen some posts recommending creating a new dataframe with just the probabilities and then graphing that.  Here is a test example of what I would like my graph to look like.

```
time <- c("t1", "t1", 
          "t2", "t2", 
          "t3", "t3", 
          "t4", "t4", 
          "t5", "t5", 
          "t6", "t6")
location <- c("L1", "L2",
              "L1", "L2",
              "L1", "L2",
              "L1", "L2",
              "L1", "L2",
              "L1", "L2")
percent <- c(67, 33,
             24, 29,
             35, 45, 
             54, 56, 
             72, 91, 
             83, 23)
test <- data.frame (time, location, percent)

ggplot (data = test, 
        mapping = aes (
          x = time, 
          y =  percent,
          group = location, 
          color = location
        )) + 
  # scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  geom_point (stat = "identity", size = 3) + 
  geom_line (stat = "identity") + 
  ggtitle("Graph of Percentage of Discharges to Home or Hospiatl by Month") + 
  xlab("Time") + 
  ylab ("Percent") +
  coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0, 100))
```

This code does work but it requires a few steps to go from the original data to a graph like this.  Is there a more direct solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your "percent" column as y values and just add a "%" sign using `paste0` in `scale_y_continuous` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot (data = test, 
        mapping = aes (
          x = time, 
          y = percent,
          group = location, 
          color = location
        )) + 
  geom_point (stat = "identity", size = 3) + 
  geom_line (stat = "identity") + 
  ggtitle("Percentage of individuals at a given location over time") + 
  xlab("Time") + 
  ylab ("Percent") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
  coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0, 100))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>